# Shut Down - exact meaning

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I don't know the exact meaning of the phrasal verb: "**Shut down**". There seems to be one little button on Windows which turns the computer off, and is called: **shut down**. Yesterday, I was watching a TV show where two siblings were competing to know who would get more customers, after a while one won it, and seeing that by winning it, he made his sister feel bad because she got fired due to lack of customers, therefore he decides to "shut his tent down" - *Guys, I can't believe you **SHUT DOWN** your tent just for me*.

So, what does "shut down" exactly mean? I have noticed that "**shut down**" may mean "turn off", but could anyone explain to me what are the others meanings?

Edit 1 - The siblings were competing to know who would get more customers by selling food in a tent. - There are also other examples using the phrasal verb "shut down", such as: *Shut her down*, *Shut me down*, *I will shut you down*. What do they mean?

I have also already heard "**Shut down**" in a game called *League of Legends*, when a player's got a kill score, like: Killed 15 players and died 0 times, and when someone kills the player with a kill score, A warning pops up saying: **Shut down**!

What does it mean? I presume it may mean something like: Stopped!

Comment: At first glance it looks as if they were selling things (operating "businesses") from tents, so presumably the relevant definition is [*if a shop, school, factory, or business **shuts down,** or if someone **shuts it down**, it **closes**, usually permanently.*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/shut-down)

Comment: Yeah, FumbleFingers, exactly.

Comment: Where did you watch that show? On YouTube? Could you please post a link to it here and tell the time when they say that?

Comment: @CookieMonster - It was on Netflix, the TV-Show is called: Jessie, it's about a girl who moved to New York in order to get a job as an actress, but she ends up becoming a Nanny of 4 rich kids of two famous directors. I will attach the image here: http://imgur.com/a/mC9Yk

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Your link got clear my question about the usage of "shut down" in that game, it set the meaning of "shut down" in games: _ to stop someone from doing something, especially to stop a player from having the freedom to move around or play well_

Comment: @DavydDiniz  there are actually more possible meanings for "shut down" than listed here.  In the context of "turning something off" it can be used figuratively to mean "shut someone up", for example.  "The moderator turned off the candidate's microphone to shut down his overly-long speech".  It can also mean "suppress", "the government moved in troops to shut down the protest".

Comment: @Andrew - So, could "Shut down" be occasionally used to imply to say to prevent something/one from doing something, to finalize or interrupt something/one or finalize something that someone is doing?

Comment: @DavydDiniz yes you hear that in movies all the time "Brilliant Scientist Hero:  "You can't shut down my project!  I'm so close to a breakthrough!"  Annoying Government Guy:  "We are shutting it down, it's cost us too much already"  And then of course the brilliant scientist guy figures it out in the next ten minutes.

Comment: Did you try a [dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/shut_down_(or_shut_something_down))?

Answer (score 15):

**to shut something down** simply means to make something nonoperational. When you shut your computer down, you bring it into a nonoperational state. If authorities shut a business down (by the way, another term that's used to refer to a company or business in English is *operation*), they legally close it down thereby making it nonoperational.

This idiom can also have a [third meaning](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/shut-down):

> 3 *[transitive] informal* to stop someone from doing something, especially to stop a player from having the freedom to move around or play well

So, to sum things up, in simple terms **shut down** just means to prevent something from keeping doing its thing by, possibly, liquidating it.

Example of a more colloquial usage:

> He tried to ask her out, but she **shut him down** completely.

This is how this expression can be used in sports:

> Our team will need to **shut down their passing game** if we are to succeed.

Comment: +1 @Cookie for inclusion of the idiomatic meaning, but I think an example would make it clearer. Something like: "He tried to ask her out, but she shut him down completely."

Answer (score 4):

To "shut down" means to stop doing business it can be used to mean either involuntary or voluntary action.

> The police raid shut down the illegal gambling operation in the basement of the liquor store.

or

> The clothing store at the mall is shutting down because it does not make enough money

It is meant in a similar way; the "shut down" button stops all operations on the computer

Comment: Got it. But what do _"shut her down"_, _"shut him down"_ mean?

Comment: To shut a person down means to stop a person from doing business or an activity of some kind. Say someone was selling food from a truck, and the police told him to stop, then you could say "the police shut him down", or "the police shut his business down", either is accurate.

Comment: So, if I were in a race against Bolt and he had won 50 races consecutively and he would have made the 51 if I hadn't won the race, so could I say: I shut him down on his last race? It would mean: I stopped him from winning his 51th race?

Comment: That wouldn't work, because its about an achievment rather than an activity, and you didn't do anything to him, you just out-competed him. Here is a sports example in which people will use "shut down" however; say you have a star player in basketball who normally scores 30 points in a game, but a very, very good defensive player on the other team got in his way, so he only scored 8 points that night. The commentators will then say that the defensive player "shut down" the star player

Comment: Well, that was almost what I meant like in the game League of Legends, when a player is in a score of 3 kills and someone kills them, doing so they will stop their consecutive, and a message will pop up saying: Shut down! That means the player who had the kill score was stopped. So I guess it should work in Bolt's example, since he had won 50 races, and I (let's suppose I'm a beginner racer) beat him in, and doing so I prevented him from winning his 51th consecutive race. Therefore, would it not be acceptable to say: "Davyd shut him down!" ?

Comment: I guess the problem is that "running" has no interaction between the competitors. You didn't do anything *to* Usain Bolt, you simply ran a faster time than him. I think the phrase implies that you actively prevented him from winning, like in league, you kill the player to shut them down.

Comment: So, to use "shut down" something that needs physical strenght or interruption has to be done?

Comment: I think "interaction" is the key. It does not need to be physical. Congress can pass a law that "shuts down" the mining industry. But it is congress doing something to the mining industry.

Comment: Hum, I see, thank you!
So, how would you list the most commonly ways to use the phrasal verb "Shut down"?

To prevent someone from keeping their score
To legally close a business

What else?

Answer (score 1):

a shutting down, as of a factory, school, or machine; a termination or suspension of operations, services, or business activity: a partial government shutdown. 
*so* any termination is called a shut down process.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider the logic behind the verb [to **shut**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/shut):

> shut (*shŭt*):
>
> - To block entrance/passage; close
> - To confine in a closed space
> - To exclude from a closed space
> - To fold up or bring together the parts of ...
> - To cause to stop operating

It may be easier to understand the different contexts where this verb and the respective phrasal verbs can be used (with a few examples):

- shut *off* – you are [*off* limits](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/off+limits) to certain place (you may not stand on or in it anymore):

  > loners who **shut** themselves **off** from the community
  >
  > <sup>[they are now isolated since they excluded themselves from there]</sup>
- shut your *mouth/eyes* – you were speaking to or looking at/after someone and you ceased this activity:

  > people who **shut their eyes** to poverty
  >
  > <sup>[no longer concerned with porverty]</sup>
- shut *up* – if you were speaking *up*, you stopped doing so:

  > I asked him politely to **shut up**
- shut *down* – something was open or [**up and running**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/up+and+running) and it went *down* (an end state):

  > - The fog **shut down** rapidly
  > - A factory was **shut down** by an inspection team
  > - The school that was **shut down** for the vacation
  > - Player X activity was **shut down** to an end
  > - **Shut down** (the long Minnesota winter) like the white lid of a box *—F. Scott Fitzgerald*

Even if you take ***down*** out in any of the examples above, the phrase's purpose remains the same.

Notice that the verb itself **connotes an action of closure or ending**, and thus its derivatives connote a similar meaning.

Answer (score 1):

> I have also already heard "Shut down" in a game called League of Legends, when a player's got a kill score, like: Killed 15 players and died 0 times

This particular usage may be confusing or paralleling the phrase for [*shut out* (definition 2)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shut%20out) (or shutout), a sports term meaning that one team was unable to score for the entire game. It isn't commonly used for all sports.